# Trying to build a dynamic PHP mysql_query string to update a row and getting back the updated row

Tags: php, ajax, mysql

I have a form that jQuery tracks the onChage `.change()` event so when something is changed it runs a ajax request and i pass in the column, id, and the values in the url.

Here i have the PHP code that should update the data. 
My question is now how do i build the mySQl string dynamically.
and how do i echo back the changes/updates that where just changed on the db.

Here is the PHP code i am trying to work with.

```
<?php require_once('Connections/connect.php'); ?>

 <?php  
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $collumn = $_GET['collumn'];
    $val = $_GET['val'];
 ?>


<?php 
    mysql_select_db($myDB, $connection);

  // here i try to build the query string and pass in the passed in values
   $sqlUpdate = 'UPDATE `plProducts`.`allPens` SET `$collumn` = '$val' WHERE `allPens`.`prodId` = '$id' LIMIT 1;';

  // here i want to echo back the updated row (or the updated data) 
  $seeResults = mysql_query($sqlUpdate, $connection);
  echo  $seeResults
?>
```

is this example OK?

```
$sqlUpdate = 'UPDATE `plProducts`.`allPens` SET "{$collumn}" = "{$val}" WHERE `allPens`.`prodId` = "{$id}"LIMIT 1;';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the string concatenation operator `.`.

```
$sqlUpdate = 'UPDATE `plProducts`.`allPens` SET `' . $collumn .'` = \'$val\' WHERE `allPens`.`prodId` = '. $id . ' LIMIT 1;';
mysql_query(mysql_escape_string($sqlUpdate));
```

Of course, this presents a whole plethora of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) loopholes.

Comment: @adardesign just echo back the $val variable.  You dont need to query the DB for it since you have it already

Comment: @Jacob can you please explain what you mean by saying "a whole plethora of SQL injection loopholes".  thanks

Comment: @adardesign, There are many ways a guy like me or you can manipulate this code from the outside. Because you are not running `mysql_escape_string` or a similar function on your SQL, there are ways that your query could return results that the hacker would want.

Comment: is this the same kind of security problem as `eval()` in javaScript?

Comment: Start by reading everything tagged [sql-injection]:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-injection

Comment: @Jacob may i ask you?  why is /$val/ wrapped? inside the slashes?

Comment: @adardesign, the backslashes are to escape the inner quotes in order so that they don't close out it's enclosing string.

Comment: Thanks, is there an option to have the `sql string`  for example  "SET  {$collumn} and {$val}"? instead of these concatenation? why am i asking? ill tell you the truth, currently it doesn't work. so maybe there is an extra ', i was thinking if we can have a cleaner string.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you can do it that way so long as the quotes are double quotes.

Comment: @jacob I posted inside the question  the last piece of code, Please let me know if this is fine.  Thanks tons.

Comment: No, this will work: `"UPDATE plProducts.allPens SET {$collumn} = {$val} WHERE allPens.prodId = {$id} LIMIT 1;"`